# Where can one travel if an Interpol notice was issued?

Tags: international-travel

If Interpol issued a notice at the request of the UAE for an Indian national, can one travel to other countries apart from those in the Gulf countries?

Comment: Interpol alert? Red corner notice? Blue corner notice? Please be more specific

Comment: I really feel that this is above the pay grade of the site! Please talk to an actual lawyer with knowledge of international law before travelling!